# jQuery onclick count previous instances

Tags: jquery, count, onclick, instance

I'm trying to click and instance of a class then count and alert the number of previous instances of that same class, currently it just seems to show all instances rather than the number before the clicked instance.

Here's the code I have currently along with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Jkv/)

HTML:

```
<div class="locationGallery">
    <div><span class="prev">next</span><span class="polaroidImage" ref="1">IMAGE 1 SIMULATION</span><span class="next"></span></div>
    <div><span class="prev">next</span><span class="polaroidImage" ref="2">IMAGE 2 SIMULATION</span><span class="next"></span></div>
    <div><span class="prev">next</span><span class="polaroidImage" ref="3">IMAGE 3 SIMULATION</span><span class="next"></span></div>
    <div><span class="prev">next</span><span class="polaroidImage" ref="4">IMAGE 4 SIMULATION</span><span class="next"></span></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var numImgs = $('div.locationGallery .polaroidImage').length;
var prevImages = $('.polaroidImage').prevAll().length;


$('.polaroidImage').click(function(){
    var title1 = $('div.locationGallery').next('.polaroidImage').attr('ref');
    alert(prevImages);
});
```

CSS:

```
.next{
     margin-left:25px; 
     display:none;
}
.prev{
     margin-right:25px; 
     display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are selecting all the `.polaroidImage` elements, also `prevAll` only selects the previous *sibling* elements of the selected element. You should select the parent elements and then select the target elements.

```
$('.polaroidImage').click(function(){
    var prevImages = $(this.parentNode).prevAll().find('.polaroidImage').length;
    alert(prevImages);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kJLy6/

In case that you want to cache the object, you can use `index` and `slice` methods:

```
var $prevImages = $('.polaroidImage');

$prevImages.click(function(){
    var index = $prevImages.index(this),
        count = $prevImages.slice(0, index).length;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TKxAP/

Comment: Thanks that's exactly the type of thing I was after

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $('.polaroidImage').click(function(){
   var title1 = $('div.locationGallery').next('.polaroidImage').attr('ref');
   var prevAll = $(this).parent().prevAll('div').length;
   alert(prevAll);
});
```